# Parse JSON String into List

Tags: c#, json, json.net

It is needed to parse JSONString into  List. (List of instances)
I'm trying to use JSON.NET by Newtonsoft.

I have classes:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Manufactorers { get; set; }

    }
```

The JSON string looks something like this:

```
[
{     
 "Column0":23.0,
 "Column1":"Евроен",
 "Column2":"https://www.123.com",
 "Column3":"Фак"
},
{
 "Column0":24.0,
 "Column1":"Еил",
 "Column2":"https://www.123.com",
 "Column3":"Старт"
}
]
```

I've been trying to do something like this:

```
string JSONString = string.Empty;
JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(JSONString);
```

But it returns 0 and null.
I have no idea, how to fix it.

Also here I truy to parse Excel file. This code works, but after deserialization, I have just 0 and null.

```
var filePath = @"..\..\..\..\doc.xlsx";

using (var steam = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(steam))
   {
       var result = reader.AsDataSet().Tables["Лист1"];

       string JSONString = string.Empty;
       JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

       List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(JSONString);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not C, is it perhaps C#? Please pay attention when selecting tags.

Comment: There are no properties named `Column0`, `Column1`... in your class. That's why the Deserialization fails

Comment: In the shown code, what is `result` ?

Comment: If I add properties named Column0, Column1, I can see this error ```Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Could not convert string to integer: ID. Path '[0].Column0', line 1, position 16.'```

Comment: ```result``` is  ```var result = reader.AsDataSet().Tables["Лист1"];```.This is part of the parsing Excel file.

Comment: Why are you serializing, then deserializing the result ?

Comment: `couse I want to have a List of instances.
Is there another option to add data from a table to a sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming of JSON and your class does not match. This can be fixed using `JsonProperty` attributes:

```
[JsonProperty("Column0")]
public decimal ID { get; set; }
```

Second, JSON deserizlizer can not deserialize string `"23.0"` to int when there is decimal point. You can retype ID to decimal or double to make it work.

Little test here:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [JsonProperty("Column0")]
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then the deserialization works without errors:

```
var testClassJson = "{\"Column0\": 12.0}";
var i = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(testClassJson);
```

Comment: It works, but with type ```string```
```[JsonProperty("Column0")]

public string ID { get; set; }```